# Store arguments of a command in variable

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, arguments, command-line-arguments, programmatically-created

I am trying to store the arguments of a command in a string instead of calling the function directly with the parameters but it seems that Powershell is not handling the string properly

```
ffmpeg -v quiet -stats ...  # works

$var = "-v quiet -stats"

ffmpeg $var ... #does not work
```

I get:

Unrecognized option 'v quiet'.                                                                                                                                                  Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

What is the correct way to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: try it like this: `$var = "-v", "quiet", "-stats"; ffmpeg @var`

Comment: In short: In order to programmatically pass arguments to external programs, construct an _array_, with each parameter (option) name and parameter value / positional argument (operand) becoming its own element. E.g., to execute `foo -o "bar baz"`, use `$a = '-o', 'bar baz'; foo $a`. See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: thanks for the hint and for linking to a similar question. Indeed, given the title of the other question, there was no way to find it unless linked to by someone who knew it already

Comment: Good point, @user206904 - I've added more tags to your question and also to the linked duplicate, and I've amended the latter's title.